# Mailto C# attachment syntax

Tags: c#, attachment, mailto

How can I attach a file to this mailto string?

```
string mailto = "mailto:" + to + "&SUBJECT=" + subject + "?BODY=" + body + 
    "&Attachment=" + attachment;
```

This doesn't work; the file isn't attached.

Comment: You're trying to attach a file to a String. That's why it's not working.

Comment: I got this issue to, where I would like to add an attachment to an email (by specifiying the link if possible, but in the end, I have the binary content if needed). The problem is that I don't have access to the user SMTP (since it can be a lot of different users) + I can't add any configuration to get the smtp information, hence the Process.Starts(mailto:...) thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes at the end of "attachment".

```
"mailto:" + to + "&SUBJECT=" + subject + "?BODY=" + body + "&Attachment=" + attachment
```

Where `attachment` has the attachment link.

Note: This will not work if the users dont have access to the attachment so you can try [attaching and sending it through a c# code](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/email/email-attach-aspnet2-csharp.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible that this does not work with all Email client,like different version of Mcrosoft Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

From what I saw on the web (and by trying it to), it is not always possible to do so. Some email client, and by some I mean lots of them, will not let you do this because it is considered a security hole. However, when it is accepted, the syntax provided by Shodan looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = string.Format("\"{0}\"", Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK")[0].Modules[0].FileName);
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" /c ipm.note /m {0} /a \"{1}\"", "someone@somewhere.com", @"c:\attachments\file.txt");
proc.Start();
```